# Foursquare API Real-Time Checkin... How to obtain venue photos?

Tags: foursquare

First off, just want to say the Foursquare API is so awesome and tidy!

So currently, I have Foursquare checkins posting back to my API's endpoint. I noticed that the venue info is "compact" (am I assuming). Is there a certain configuration parameter that I can change to obtain verbose venue data? I don't really want to have to make an additional call to  FS to obtain venue photo urls...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Venue photos are not returned in the check-in response. To get the complete venue data, you can use the venue detail endpoint (https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/venues). If you are only interested in photos, you can use the venues/photos endpoint (https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/photos)

Comment: Cool that works :) Although originally I was hoping to avoid making an extra call to FS. Guess it's unavoidable. Thanks for the reply!